# Angular JS - Bind drop down (ng-options) to custom object and show selected value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

What I want is to show the initial value on ddl when I open the edit book form. But it does not show any value, see the code I am using to bind the ddl- the newbook and author is JSON data as defined above.

Drop down is bind to author json array in format this format -

```
{id:1, Name: XYZ}
```

and this ddl is part of edit form for books which have below format -

```
newbook = {
    Id:bctx.bookDetail.Id,
    Author: { Id: bctx.bookDetail.AuthorId, Name: bctx.bookDetail.AuthorName },
    Genre: bctx.bookDetail.Genre,
    Price: bctx.bookDetail.Price,
    Title: bctx.bookDetail.Title,
    Year: bctx.bookDetail.Year
};   


<select ng-options="author as author.Name for author in actrl.authors" ng-model="bctrl.newbook.Author" required>
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Got it fixed, using ng-options="author as author.Name for author in actrl.authors track by author.Id"

Answer (score 0):

I think select options can be only simple objects, hence you might want to change your selection to id (or any other numberic/string values). You can retrieve the actual selected author object in the controller by listening to the change event.

After going over [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), you might look into "track by" to enable complex object selection.

Comment: Your answer helped .. I was able to fix the problem.. Wish to mark it as answer but does not have enough reputation .. Thanks ..

Comment: I don't think you need reputation to mark it as answer. You will just have to wait a little. It should show you how long though. @narendrabagdwal

Comment: Thx @narendrabagdwal. Could you please tell us what was the specific fix?

Comment: Got it fixed, using ng-options="author as author.Name for author in actrl.authors track by author.Id"